# Cannot form a select statement for query in silverlight

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to do something like

- from table1
- where col5="abcd"
- select col1

I did like

```
        query_ = From g In DomainService.GetGEsQuery Select New GE With {.Desc = g.codDesc}
```

"This cause a runtime error, i tried various combinations but failed"

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your trying to do this on the client side. If so you could do something like this

```
          DomainService.Load(DomainService.GetGEsQuery().Where(g => g.codDesc == "something"), lo =>
            {
                if (lo.HasError == false)
                {
                    List<string> temp = lo.Entities.Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
                }
            }, null);
```

you could also do this in the server side (which i would personally prefer) like this

```
        public IQueryable<string> GetGEStringList(string something)
        {

            return this.ObjectContext.GE.Where(g => g.codDesc == something).Select(a => a.Name);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

DomainService.GetGEsQuery() returns an IQueryable, **that is only useful in a subsequent asynchronous load**. Your are missing the () on the method call, but that is only the first problem.

You can apply filter operations to the query returned using `Where` etc, but it still needs to be passed to the `Load` method of your domain context (called `DomainService` in your example).

The example Jack7 has posted shows an *anonymous callback* from the load method which then accesses the results inside the load object `lo` and extracts just the required field with another query. Note that you can filter the query in RIA services, but not change the basic return type (i.e. you cannot filter out unwanted columns on the client-side).

Jack7's second suggestion to implement a specific method server-side, returning just the data you want, is your best option.